# Getting text of element without including text of sub-element with jsoup

Tags: css-selectors, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to parse HTML. There are list items that look like this:

```
<li><span class="chk">X</span>Category Name</li>
```

I want to get the text of the li NOT including the text of the span. So I want to get "Category Name" without the "X". (If I invoke the `text()` method on the li element, I get "XCategory Name".) How can I exclude the sub-span?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ownText()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29) method will help you here.

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("<ul><li><span class=\"chk\">X</span>Home</li><li><spanclass=\"chk\">X</span>Category Name</li></ul>");
Elements elems = document.select("li");
for(Element elem : elems){
    System.out.println(elem.ownText());
}
```