# How to select sibling text node in Jsoup?

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, jsoup

I want to select sibling text node of an element. This is how I select it in XPath

```
//div[@class='someclass']/following-sibling::node()
```

Above code would select text SALAAM in XPath

```
<foo>
  <div class='someclass'/>
  SALAAM
  <bar>something</bar>
</foo>
```

Is this possible with JSoup selectors? I don't want to code java, just need some sizzle-like selector.

**Please note** that this is is different from [Getting text of element without including text of sub-element with jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765069/getting-text-of-element-without-including-text-of-sub-element-with-jsoup), because the answer there is not pure selector expression.

Comment: Yes I tried, no avail. CSS don't consider text nodes as a real node, so no way to specify it in CSS. When you say ''siblingA + siblingB'', what do you put for siblingB when it's actually a text node not an html tag element?

Comment: The JSoup selectors do not support selecting text nodes. So, selecting the text node's container is as close as you can get.

Comment: Added some description. Thanks @Tomalak. I believe jsoup selectors do not select text nodes.

Comment: Selecting the parent or an adjacent element sibling and then using the DOM API to grab the interesting node should not be too difficult, though.

Comment: Yes I know. But here I cannot code java. My app just accepts selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock. I think that this is not a duplicate, since OP asking how to do this using a CSS selector, and not how to do it in code.

Comment: Fair enough. The answer will most likely point to the solution there however, as it is simply not possible to do it without code.

Comment: You could [convert your Jsoup Document to an org.w3c.dom.Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802445/unable-to-convert-jsoup-document-to-w3c-document) and then use XPath on that.

Comment: Only a small correction—your XPath selector selects SALAAM but the `<bar/>` sibling as well (it selects all following siblings). You could use `//div[@class='someclass']/following-sibling::node()[1]` or `//div[@class='someclass']/following-sibling::text()`.